# Bulk edit post date in wordpress

Tags: date, bulk

I need to edit the date of several posts, change it to a specific date, all posts should have the same date.

How can I achieve this? Is there any fuction to add to the functions.php to add this feature?
I cant find a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Original source : [post date](http://www.quora.com/WordPress-Plugins/How-can-I-bulk-change-post-date)

1. Create ***admin-script.js*** at your current theme ( *this use js folder* )

   ```
   jQuery(document).ready(function($){
       $('.inline-edit-col-right .inline-edit-col')
           .append(
               '<label style="margin-top: 3em;"><span class="title">Date</span>'
               + '<div class="timestamp-wrap"><select name="mm">'
               + '<option value="00">Month</option>'
               + '<option value="01">01-January</option>'
               + '<option value="02">02-February</option>'
               + '<option value="03">03-March</option>'
               + '<option value="04">04-April</option>'
               + '<option value="05">05-May</option>'
               + '<option value="06">06-June</option>'
               + '<option value="07">07-July</option>'
               + '<option value="08">08-August</option>'
               + '<option value="09">09-September</option>'
               + '<option value="10">10-October</option>'
               + '<option value="11">11-November</option>'
               + '<option value="12">12-December</option>'
               + '</select>'
               + '<input type="text" autocomplete="off" name="jj" maxlength="2" size="2" value="d" placeholder="d">'
               + ', <input type="text" autocomplete="off" name="aa" maxlength="4" size="4" value="Y" placeholder="Y">'
               + '@ <input type="text" autocomplete="off" name="hh" maxlength="2" size="2" value="H" placeholder="H">'
               + ' : <input type="text" autocomplete="off" name="mn" maxlength="2" size="2" value="i" placeholder="i"></div></label>'
       );
   });
   ```

   2. Add this to your ***functions.php*** theme file

.

```
function my_enqueue() {
wp_enqueue_script('my_admin_script', get_bloginfo('template_url') . '/js/admin-script.js', array('jquery'), false, true);
}
add_action('admin_init', 'my_enqueue');

function my_bulk_edit($action, $result){
    if ('bulk-posts' == $action && $_GET['mm']!='00' && isset($_GET['jj']) && isset($_GET['aa']) && isset($_GET['hh']) && isset($_GET['mn']) ) {
        $date = $_GET['aa'].'-'.$_GET['mm'].'-'.$_GET['jj'].' '.$_GET['hh'].':'.$_GET['mn'].':00';
        $post_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($date));
        $post_date_gmt = gmdate("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime($date));
        $post_status = (strtotime($post_date) > strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s")))? 'future' : 'publish';

        $post_IDs = array_map('intval', (array) $_GET['post']);
        foreach ($post_IDs as $post_ID) {
            $post_data = array( 'ID' => $post_ID, 'post_date' => $post_date, 'post_date_gmt' => $post_date_gmt, 'post_status' => $post_status, 'edit_date' => true );
            //wp_insert_post( $post_data );
            wp_update_post( $post_data );
        }

    }
}
add_action('check_admin_referer', 'my_bulk_edit', 10, 2);
```

Here the **screenshot**

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

> all posts should have the same date

Do you mean "all posts on this site" or "some posts on this site"?

If the former, perhaps you should be using pages instead of posts?