# Randomised Post Time

Tags: pagination, mysql, date-time, timestamp

I've imported a Drupal site to Wordpress with an archive of 1000s of posts which had been backdated by adding a custom taxonomy 'Year' rather than by adjusting the post date.

I've been able to remove this unneccessary taxonomy by bulk editing the post date on the using this method
[Bulk edit post date in wordpress](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/176819/bulk-edit-post-date-in-wordpress#184927)

However, I now have many posts that were published at exactly the same date, hour and minute. This works fine for the archives, it doesn't work for the next/previous pagination, which skips over posts published at exactly the same time.

Any ideas how I could
a) reset and randomise the post time of all posts, keeping the existing date?
b) correct the pagination so it can somehow recognise posts published at the same time?